# SFGUI running lot of GL errors

Tags: c++, opengl, sfgui

I have compile SFGUI 0.3.0 with TDM 5.1.0 via cmake makefile. SFML is 2.5.1 and correct compile version. Everything is an order and I receive sfgui.dll and libsfgui.a as I expected. Now i'm trying to use library very simple code like

```
#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>
#include <SFGUI/Widgets.hpp>

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main() {
    // Create SFML's window.
    sf::RenderWindow render_window( sf::VideoMode( 800, 600 ), "Hello world!" );

    // Create an SFGUI. This is required before doing anything with SFGUI.
    sfg::SFGUI sfgui;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and linking generates no errors but running.

> GL Error detected at NonLegacyRenderer.cpp:L88
>   GLEXT_glGetHandle( GLEXT_GL_PROGRAM_OBJECT )
>   Error: GL_INVALID_OPERATION

.
.
.

> GL Error detected at NonLegacyRenderer.cpp:L185
>   GLEXT_glDeleteVertexArrays( 1, &m_vao )
>   Error: GL_INVALID_OPERATION

I have all sfml*.dll and sfgui.dll same folder as my executable. How may I solve this problem?

My compile command is 
g++ -g -c -O -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu++11 -lsfml-system -lsfml-window -lsfml-graphics -lsfgui -lglu32 -o hello.exe

Comment: Naming a renderer wich calls `glGetHandleARB` _NonLegacy_ is kind of satire in my book. That function was never part of OpenGL, but of the early shader extensions which are completely outdated and superseded by OpenGL 2.0 back in _2004_.

Comment: Do you get the same errors with a full main-loop? Maybe terminating the application right after creating the necessary objects isn't liked by SFGUI? 
Also the linking order is wrong, it needs to follow the rule of thumb "If x depends on y, x needs to come before y", so sfgui, sfml-graphics, sfml-window, sfml-system

Comment: Actually i just downloaded a newer version of SFGUI 0.4.0 and upadeted my GPU. Now it seems to work until OpenGL related error messages keeps printing console while running the program. I check later if I find better version of driver.